How to throw exception with super constructor been mocked
I have an exception class
public class FooStudioException extends SpamException {

    public FooStudioException(String message, String localizedMessage, Throwable cause) {
        super(SpamErrorCodes.INTERNAL_ERROR, message, localizedMessage, cause);
    }

    public FooStudioException(String message, String localizedMessage) {
        super(SpamErrorCodes.INTERNAL_ERROR, message, localizedMessage);
    }
}

public class SpamException extends Exception {
    .....
    public SpamException(SpamErrorCodes codes, String message, String localizedMessage, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        .....
    }

which is been used inside a method
public class FooInstrumentAspect extends InstrumentAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(Foo.aop.annotation.FooInstrument)")
    public void FooInstrumentPointcut() {}

    @Around("FooInstrumentPointcut()")
    public Object aroundFooInstrumented(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return aroundInstrumented(pjp);
        } catch (FooStudioException ex) {
            throw ex.getCause();
        }
    }
}

@Aspect
public class InstrumentAspect {

........
     */
    @Around("instrumentPointcut()")
    public Object aroundInstrumented(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {



        Object result = null;
        Throwable throwable = null;

        try {
            result = pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throwable = t;
        }
        if (throwable != null) {
            throw throwable;
        }

        return result;
    }


I would like to throw the exception FooStudioException when pjp.proceed is called. But I would also want to ensure when FooStudioException is been thrown, constructor of SpamException is mocked.
How can I achieve it?
I am ready to use powermock if required.

When does your class throw? Can't you call it with an input that triggers the exception?

Mocking a behavior of the superclass is a common request, but not one that can be done readily regardless of Powermock or Mockito 5.0. The relationship between the subclass and superclass is necessarily tightly-coupled in Java, and that is even more true regarding constructor behavior. Exceptions are usually pretty harmless in their creation, though—why are you trying to avoid calling the constructor of an Exception?

@JeffBowman Consider the fact that the superclass is part of a library my team does not own and we do not have the bandwidth to fix it. The code is badly written, without DI, making n/w calls during class construction et. al.

@knittl Unfortunately there is no way to shortcut the code to skip triggering the exception

@Abhijit You don't have to convince me. Neither of us is going to be able to talk the language out of its inherent rules.
